# Jenkins text finder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Im currently working with this Jenkins Plugin
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/text-finder/
https://plugins.jenkins.io/text-finder/#documentation
I`ve tried to make a  pipline and do the following:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                findText(textFinders: [textFinder(regexp: '<Started by>', alsoCheckConsoleOutput: true, buildResult: 'UNSTABLE')])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code succeeds, finds the desired text, but buildResult/unstableIfFound parameters seem to never work for me: the job finishes with SUCCESS status. Can anybody help me with that? Or recommend any other option to parse Jenkins console logs and mark the build unstable in some cases ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using `manager.log` feature parse the jenkins console log output. Please install `postbuild plugin` and then try

```
     try {
        something
      } catch (e) {
        if ( manager.logContains('.*Add the text message which you want find and mark build unstable.*') {
          catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            error('The build is failed because above test.')
          }
        }
```

Comment: cant make this work for some reason
can you please give some more workaround?

Comment: ok i found groovy postbuild plugin and it works nice. thanks!